# Loop through query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @files TABLE (DocumentID Varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @files (DocumentID)
SELECT DISTINCT D.DocumentID
FROM Documents D
WHERE D.DocumentID IN ('637542', '655437', '655900') --example for debugging

-- loop
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @rowCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @files)

WHILE @i <= @rowCount
BEGIN
   DECLARE @id Varchar(50) = (SELECT DocumentID FROM @files WHERE ROW_NUMBER() = @i)
   EXEC dbo.bom @docuid=@id
   SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

This code gives me the following errors:

```
Msg 10753, Level 15, State 3, Line 19
The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 20
Must declare the scalar variable "@id".
```

How can I declare an OVER clause if I'm using @i there and what does exactly the scalar variable message mean?

As the procdeure name might suggest, it prints a bill of materials for the selected docid. I'd like to print boms of multiple files to one dataset.

When executing the procedure once, it looks like this:

| docuid | description | etc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 637542 | value a | value x |

What I need, looks like this:

| docuid | description | etc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 637542 | value a | value x |
| 355437 | value b | value y |
| 655900 | value c | value z |

Comment: Don't use record numbers; there's no such thing in SQL Server. Use a [cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql) instead.

Comment: What does your `bom` procedure actually do? Can you show the code? Probably best to not use a cursor and rather do it all as one query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @InDocumentID VARCHAR(50);
SET @InDocumentID='';
DECLARE cCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
   SELECT DISTINCT D.DocumentID
   FROM Documents AS D
   WHERE D.DocumentID IN ('637542', '655437', '655900');
OPEN cCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM cCursor INTO @InDocumentID;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
  EXEC dbo.bom @docuid=@InDocumentID;
  FETCH NEXT FROM cCursor INTO @InDocumentID;
END
CLOSE cCursor;
DEALLOCATE cCursor;
```

I would try standard cursor approach

Comment: Thank you! This prints out three separate datasets but I can manage to combine those.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same style but make it work, you need to add your own index/row column to `@files` (for example, via `IDENTITY`).

```sql
DECLARE @files TABLE (RN INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED , DocumentID Varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @files (DocumentID)
SELECT DISTINCT D.DocumentID
FROM Documents D
WHERE D.DocumentID IN ('637542', '655437', '655900') --example for debugging

-- loop
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @rowCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @files)

DECLARE @id Varchar(50)
WHILE @i <= @rowCount
BEGIN
    SET @id = (SELECT DocumentID FROM @files WHERE RN = @i)
   EXEC dbo.bom @docuid=@id
   SET @i = @i + 1
END
```